# Add shortcut to SmcFanControl?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, script, fan, smc

SmcFanControl is an application on OS X that lets you create profiles for the fan and increase/decrease their speed as you wish.
The problem, there's no shortcut on the app, to change the profile you have to browse it every time, The creator claims that the application is not scriptable, although by doing some research I found some applescripts to do other stuff I'm not interested in.

So what I want, is to create an applescript or a shell script or whatever it is, to allow controlling the fans with keyboard shortcut, for example :

Key1 : +200RPM 
Key2 : -200RPM
If RPM is 2000 then stop Key1
If RPM is 6200 then stop Key2

I know that my example is kinda fudgy but I hope you get it 
That's it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, with some work required on your end.

SmcFanControl has a built in utility `smc` ([documentation](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command)) that you can use from the command line. You can do things like set and read fan speed. That's the only way to possibly create the shortcuts you want (because as you said, you can't create a shortcut to the profiles within the app itself.

### AppleScript with `smc`

An AppleScript to run a terminal command:

```
do shell script "command"
```

A terminal command to set both of the fans in a Macbook Pro to 3500 RPM:

> Line **1** takes the fans out of automatic mode
>
> Line **2** sets fan 0 (left) to 3500 RPM
>
> Line **3** sets fan 1 (right) to 3500 RPM

```
smc -k "FS! " -w 0003
smc -k F0Tg -w 36b0
smc -k F1Tg -w 36b0
```

Now our AppleScript looks like:

```
do shell script "smc -k "FS! " -w 0003;smc -k F0Tg -w 36b0;smc -k F1Tg -w 36b0"
```

### Keyboard Shortcut

Okay so you have your AppleScript. Now we follow [**this guide**](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/09/assign-keyboard-shortcut-applescript-automator-service/) to assign a keyboard shortcut to our AppleScript. I'll sum it up:

1. Open Automator and create a new service
2. Choose the `Service` template, select `Utilities` from the Library, and double-click `Run AppleScript`.
3. Replace the `Your script goes here` portion with the script above (`do shell script "smc -k "FS! " -w 0003;smc -k F0Tg -w 36b0;smc -k F1Tg -w 36b0"`).
4. Change the first box at the top where it says `Service receives selected text in any application` to `no input`
5. Name your service and remember the name (It's case sensitive)
6. Open the `Keyboard Shortcuts` pane in the Keyboard panel in System Preferences
7. Click the plus sign to add a new shortcut and enter the name of the service **exactly as you typed above**.
8. Assign a key to activate it and you’re ready to go.

> Now whenever you press that key, in any application or context, it will run your AppleScript command

### Finishing Notes

This should give you a good idea of how to do this the way you want to (making multiple shortcuts for increase and decrease of RPMs) Read the [**documentation**](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command) for `smc` to learn how to set the fans to other RPMs, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir, this is insane! (You know what I mean :p )
Thank you very much